# Adding header to tsv file through terminal

Tags: bash, unix

I have many tsv files that are headerless, and would like to add the same header to each of them. How can I do this through the terminal or bash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 sed -i '1i \here comes header' files
```

files could be glob exp, like `*.txt`

Comment: Could you explain what the `1i` does?

Comment: line `1`, do `insert`

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have header in "head", tsv files as "body", how about `cat head body | tee body`

Comment: Or `cat - filein > fileout <<< "THE HEADER"`

Comment: you need something like  `...>fileout && mv fileout filein` to save "in place"

Comment: @Kent just learned the tee command, quite interesting http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/